# How to calculate frontages of city parcel data in ArcMap 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, geoprocessing

I need to calculate the length of polygon frontages (along streets) from our city's parcel (i.e. lot) data in order to do an analysis on lot frontages in various zoning districts. How can I do this?

Comment: There are a few examples here http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1384&t=120396

Comment: Do you have a right of way shapefile?

Answer (score 4):

Possible solution, however you should provide a lot more detail in your question if you really want to narrow things down (license level available, formats of the data involved, what else you have besides parcel polygons, etc.):

1. Buffer street centerlines by something more than the width of the
   road. This may require multiple centerline selections and buffers or
   not. The goal is you want to *completely* enclose any parcel
   frontage line in the buffer and ensure side/rear lines are at least
   *partially* outside the buffer.
2. Run Feature to Lines on the parcel data, and then Split Line at
   Vertices on the resulting line file. This should give you the parcel
   lines as individual lines, with attributes that link them back to
   their parent parcels.
3. Run a Select by Location to select all parcel lines that are
   *completely within* the buffer layer. Export to a new file or invert the selection and delete the other (side/rear) lines.
4. At this point you can Intersect (careful with overlaps at street intersections) or Spatial Join the remaining lines and buffers to
   get the street ID/name as an attribute of the frontage lines, or
   whatever else you may need for your analysis in terms of attribute
   transfer. You may also want to create an attribute field and field
   calculate the length of the lines into it so you have a permanent
   attribute that isn't a system managed field.

Comment: Unfortunately, this probably won't work because streets have various widths. I'm trying to calculate lot frontage for the entire city and major arterials would require a 100' buffer that could add complete parcels where two streets come together at angles. Plus, street centerlines are drawn improperly (they don't always end at the end of roads) so I think we need a process that's more about just the parcels. Is there a way to separate out the lines that are not shared (that is, parcel lines along the frontage that don't share a lot line)?

Comment: Btw, we have most extensions available but still on ArcMap 10.0.

Comment: @VaidilaSatvika That would heavily depend on the structure of the parcels. Assume they're all polygons and a given side is either a frontage (no overlap with any other line), or a side or rear that is also shared by another lot. In such a case you could convert the parcels to lines and use a topology/must not overlap rule; or run a spatial join, which should give you a count column. Anything with a count greater than 0 would be a stacked line and therefore not a frontage. But this quickly breaks down when you have alleys or other parcel lines that are neither frontage or adjoining another lot.

Comment: Another alternative mentioned at the link in Mapperz comment would be to dissolve all parcels, then use those dissolved lines (may need to convert the dissolved parcel layer to lines as well, but they needn't be individual segments) as a check against the parcels converted to individual lines. If they intersect/share boundary with/whichever method the dissolved version, they're frontage. Could explore the Aggregate Polygons tool for this as well. But again, alleys and non-adjacent parcels will throw in false positives here as well.

Comment: I used this same process and it was very successful.  It is not perfect due to parcel polygons not always having the expected shape following a road, but generally it was correct.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at this solution https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_SolutionCenter/gw_calc_street_frontages.htm

Finally I have come with an answer using only native ArcMap Tools:
The followed steps below

1. Convert the parcel feature to line using feature to line
2. Use intersect tool to find intersected lines using as the only input the converted lines on step 1. This tool will give us only the internal lines
3. Use select by location with the input layer being the converted lines, and the selecting features the lines result from the intersect.
   NOTE THE INVERT SELECTION CHECKED
   [image]
4. Save the selection as a new layer.
   [image]
5. End of story.

Tested on ArcGIS 10.3

Maybe this can help.